# In terms of noise, how does a steep climb-out compare to a noise abatement procedure?

Tags: airport, noise, noise-reduction

For airports in populated areas, it is common to implement noise abatement procedures. In practice, this means that aircraft reduce thrust on departure, so that noise is reduced in proximity to the airport.

However, this does mean that aircraft spend a longer time at a lower altitude, which may be bad news for populated areas further away from the airport. I am wondering how noise abatement procedures affect areas further away, up to 150km away from the airport. I would like to know how this compares quantitatively (e.g., a dB(A) chart like below, for larger distances) between procedures.

[image]

<sup>Image: Hamamci et al. (2017). Determining characteristics of lands affected by noise pollution of airports. Fresenius Environmental Bulletin. 26. 69-74.</sup>

Comment: I've not read this, but it looks like this paper would be interesting to you: https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/ERCD9841.PDF

Comment: Some noise abatement procedures do implement a steeper than normal climb out by delaying the flap/slat retraction and acceleration phase of the departure to a higher altitude.

Comment: It’s a bit more difficult than the question suggests. Most airlines do reduced thrust takeoff not for noise but for engine life reasons. Once thrust is reduced to climb thrust, typically around 1000ft-1500ft above departure airfield, thrust will be roughly the same regardless of whether noise was a consideration or not. The main variation introduced by noise abatement profiles is when to accelerate, retract flaps and reduce thrust from takeoff setting. These are important considerations around the airfield, but at 150km there will be more difference due e.g. different weights than procedures..